# Re-rendering inside an event handler

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import { useState } from "react";
function Square({ value, onSquareClick, winning }) {
  console.log(winning);
  return (
    <button
      className={winning ? "newsquare" : "square"}
      onClick={onSquareClick}
    >
      {value}
    </button>
  );
}

function Board({ xIsNext, squares, onPlay, winning, handleWinning }) {
  let winner;
  function handleClick(i) {
    if (calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]) {
      return;
    }
    const nextSquares = squares.slice();
    if (xIsNext) {
      nextSquares[i] = "X";
    } else {
      nextSquares[i] = "O";
    }
    onPlay(nextSquares);
    winner = calculateWinner(nextSquares);
    console.log(squares + " "); // <----------------------------------here
    if (winner) handleWinning(winner);
  }
  console.log(squares + " ");   // <----------------------------------here
  let status;
  if (winner) {
    status = "Winner: " + squares[winner[0]];
    console.log(winner);
  } else {
    status = "Next player: " + (xIsNext ? "X" : "O");
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="status">{status}</div>
      <div className="board-row">
        <Square
          value={squares[0]}
          onSquareClick={() => handleClick(0)}
          winning={winning[0]}
        />
        <Square
          value={squares[1]}
          onSquareClick={() => handleClick(1)}
          winning={winning[1]}
        />
        <Square
          value={squares[2]}
          onSquareClick={() => handleClick(2)}
          winning={winning[2]}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="board-row">
        <Square
          value={squares[3]}
          onSquareClick={() => handleClick(3)}
          winning={winning[3]}
        />
        <Square
          value={squares[4]}
          onSquareClick={() => handleClick(4)}
          winning={winning[4]}
        />
        <Square
          value={squares[5]}
          onSquareClick={() => handleClick(5)}
          winning={winning[5]}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="board-row">
        <Square
          value={squares[6]}
          onSquareClick={() => handleClick(6)}
          winning={winning[6]}
        />
        <Square
          value={squares[7]}
          onSquareClick={() => handleClick(7)}
          winning={winning[7]}
        />
        <Square
          value={squares[8]}
          onSquareClick={() => handleClick(8)}
          winning={winning[8]}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default function Game() {
  const [history, setHistory] = useState([Array(9).fill(null)]);
  const [currentMove, setCurrentMove] = useState(0);
  const [winning, setWinning] = useState(Array(9).fill(false));
  const xIsNext = currentMove % 2 === 0;
  const currentSquares = history[currentMove];

  function handlePlay(nextSquares) {
    const nextHistory = [...history.slice(0, currentMove + 1), nextSquares];
    setHistory(nextHistory);
    setCurrentMove(nextHistory.length - 1);
  }
  function handleWinning(winningSquare) {
    const newWinning = winning.slice();
    newWinning[winningSquare[0]] = true;
    newWinning[winningSquare[1]] = true;
    newWinning[winningSquare[2]] = true;
    setWinning(newWinning);
  }
  function jumpTo(nextMove) {
    setCurrentMove(nextMove);
  }

  const moves = history.map((squares, move) => {
    let description;
    if (move > 0) {
      description = "Go to move #" + move;
    } else {
      description = "Go to game start";
    }
    return (
      <li key={move}>
        <button onClick={() => jumpTo(move)}>{description}</button>
      </li>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className="game">
      <div className="game-board">
        <Board
          xIsNext={xIsNext}
          squares={currentSquares}
          onPlay={handlePlay}
          winning={winning}
          handleWinning={handleWinning}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="game-info">
        <ol>{moves}</ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function calculateWinner(squares) {
  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
      const winningSquares = lines[i].slice();
      console.log(winningSquares);
      return winningSquares;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

I am currently working on a React.js application for a tic-tac-toe game, and I've encountered an issue with the console log output while handling state updates. After reading about React's state updates and re-rendering behavior, I expected both console.log(squares) statements to show the same output.

I would like to understand the reason behind this behavior and how I can ensure that both console.log(squares) statements show the same output.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React updates as well as the state changes are asynchronous with react. This means that when you call onPlay, the "squares" state is uploaded, but handleClick does not wait at this point to see if the state has actually been set. So you get the output before the update.

If your main concern is to get a console.log on status updates, you could use the useEffect hook

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log(squares);
}, [squares]);
```

you can also use this hook as a kind of callback as soon as a state has been changed

Ref: https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect

Comment: My concern was that I wanted to use the updated value of squares directly inside the event handler after it gets updated due to re-rendering, can we do that somehow?

Comment: use ```nextSquares``` inside your sync code block.  you can't guarantee that the updated state will be available within the same function call where the state change was initiated. You generally can't and shouldn't expect to use the updated state directly after calling a state setter function in the same synchronous block of code.

Just remember, nextSquares will be the new state of squares after re-rendering, but within the same function or event handler, the state update hasn't happened yet.
The React way of handling side effects based on state or prop changes is useEffect

Comment: Thank you, it really helped. +1 (Waiting a bit more before accepting to get more answer)

Comment: would love if you might accept my answer :)